# A binary counter problem

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, counter, cascade

How can I create a digital counter that counts from 000 to 111 and automatically starts reverse counting from 111 to 000. I have tried with simulation it works fine, but with actual ICs I am not getting a proper output.

The following is the hand-made version of the circuit diagram that I simulated on cedar:

[image]

[original fuzzy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGU75.jpg)

The top ones are 7 D flip-flops and the bottom ones are three JK flip-flops implementing the up-down counter.

Comment: Post code you used with simulation.

Comment: Actually I have done the simulation using a softwar3 called cedar . I have the .circ file if you say

Comment: Where I have used 7 dff in series to create a delay of 7 clock cycles. The dff are initially hence for the first 7 cycles the output from the seventh dff is 0. The negation of the 7th dff output is sent back to inpit for 1st dff hence for next 7 clock cycles I will get 1 as output. These outputs from 7th dff are sent to a up-down binary counter hence for the first 7 clock cycles the circuit counts up and for other 7 clock cycles it counts down

Comment: That was my logic. If you have something better idea please let mw know.

Comment: Then post resulting circuit diagram.

Comment: Post a picture of the simulated circuit.  Cedar seems to work much like other simulators, so you can make screenshot of your simulated circuit.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Those 7 D FF's seem to be a ring counter? Do you know anything about the initial state of those ff's?

Comment: IMO a better approach would be to create a 4 bit counter, where the 4'th bit controls whether the other bits count up or down.

Comment: I initially tried to reset it to 0 by  applying ground to the 1st dff and without the back connection

Comment: @Wouter can u plz elaborate a bit

Comment: And how will we change the 4th bit value automatically?

Comment: I strongly suggest you add a reset to all register before doing any more debugging on the 'real' chips.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen  I like this idea but this would be better served with a 12 count counter as the middle counts are counted in both directions and the terminal counts are only counted once (or twice if a long pause at the terminals is allowed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

[image: forward and reverse bin counter]

*View the [simulation in falstad.com](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0A193%20112%20144%20176%20144%200%200%0A193%20464%20144%20496%20144%200%200%0A193%20832%20144%20864%20144%200%200%0AR%2096%2096%2096%2064%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%2096%2096%2096%20144%200%0Aw%2096%20144%20112%20144%200%0Aw%20112%20176%2096%20176%200%0AR%2064%20240%2016%20240%201%202%20100%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Aw%2096%20176%2096%20240%200%0Aw%2096%20240%2064%20240%200%0Aw%2096%20240%20448%20240%200%0Aw%20448%20240%20448%20176%200%0Aw%20448%20176%20464%20176%200%0Aw%20448%20240%20816%20240%200%0Aw%20816%20240%20816%20176%200%0Aw%20816%20176%20832%20176%200%0Aw%20224%20144%20208%20144%200%0Aw%20576%20144%20560%20144%200%0Aw%20944%20144%20928%20144%200%0Ag%201008%20608%201008%20640%200%0A150%20976%20-112%201072%20-112%200%203%200%205%0Aw%20944%20-96%20944%20144%200%0A156%201152%20144%201168%20144%200%200%0Aw%20816%20240%201120%20240%200%0Aw%201120%20240%201120%20176%200%0Aw%201120%20176%201152%20176%200%0Aw%201152%20144%201120%20144%200%0Aw%201120%20144%201120%20-112%200%0A150%20976%20-32%201072%20-32%200%203%200%205%0Aw%201120%20-112%201072%20-112%200%0Aw%20976%20-96%20944%20-96%200%0Aw%20976%20-112%20576%20-112%200%0Aw%20928%20208%20960%20208%200%0Aw%20960%20208%20960%20-16%200%0Aw%20960%20-16%20976%20-16%200%0A154%20320%20128%20416%20128%200%202%200%205%0A154%20640%20128%20736%20128%200%202%200%205%0Aw%201248%20144%201264%20144%200%0Aw%201264%20144%201264%2016%200%0A150%20736%2064%20832%2064%200%202%200%205%0Aw%20576%20144%20576%20-112%200%0Aw%20224%20-48%20224%20144%200%0Aw%20320%20144%20224%20144%200%0Aw%20416%20128%20448%20128%200%0Aw%20448%20128%20448%20144%200%0Aw%20448%20144%20464%20144%200%0Aw%20736%2080%20736%20128%200%0Aw%20832%2064%20832%20144%200%0Aw%20736%2048%20448%2048%200%0Aw%20448%2048%20448%20128%200%0A157%201168%20464%201200%20464%200%0A197%201040%20464%201120%20464%200%0Aw%201168%20592%201232%20592%200%0Aw%201168%20624%201264%20624%200%0Aw%201264%20624%201264%20592%200%0Aw%201168%20656%201296%20656%200%0Aw%201296%20656%201296%20592%200%0Aw%20224%20-48%20224%20-128%200%0Aw%20224%20-128%20976%20-128%200%0Aw%20944%20144%20944%20496%200%0Aw%20944%20496%201040%20496%200%0Aw%201008%20608%201008%20464%200%0Aw%201008%20464%201040%20464%200%0Aw%20576%20144%20576%20528%200%0Aw%20576%20528%201040%20528%200%0Aw%20224%20144%20224%20560%200%0Aw%20224%20560%201040%20560%200%0Ax%201139%20254%201277%20257%204%2024%20Direction%5CsCtrl%0Ax%20145%20117%20177%20120%204%2024%20Q1%0Ax%20495%20119%20527%20122%204%2024%20Q2%0Ax%20864%20117%20896%20120%204%2024%20Q3%0Ax%201183%20117%201215%20120%204%2024%20Q4%0Ax%201007%20-103%201036%20-100%204%2024%20A1%0Ax%201007%20-25%201036%20-22%204%2024%20A2%0Aw%20320%20112%20288%20112%200%0Aw%20288%2016%20288%20112%200%0Aw%20208%20208%20256%20208%200%0Aw%20256%20208%20256%20-48%200%0Aw%20256%20-48%20976%20-48%200%0Aw%201152%20208%201088%20208%200%0Aw%201088%20208%201088%20-32%200%0Aw%201088%20-32%201072%20-32%200%0Aw%20640%20144%20576%20144%200%0Aw%20640%20112%20640%2016%200%0Aw%20640%2016%20288%2016%200%0Aw%20640%2016%201264%2016%200%0Aw%20560%20208%20608%20208%200%0Aw%20608%20208%20608%20-32%200%0Aw%20608%20-32%20976%20-32%200%0Ax%20351%20133%20380%20136%204%2024%20X1%0Ax%20672%20136%20701%20139%204%2024%20X2%0A)*

To build it<sup>1</sup>, I started with a simple 3-bit "up" counter, similar to the one below - except I used T-flip flops for simplicity, and we only need the first three stages.

[image: up counter from allaboutcircuits.com]

*image credit: [www.allaboutcircuits.com](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-11/synchronous-counters/)*

And a "down" counter:

[image: down counter from allaboutcircuits.com]

*image credit: [www.allaboutcircuits.com](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-11/synchronous-counters/)*

The goal is to have the circuit change from an "up" counter to a "down" counter, and vice versa, when the outputs become binary *111* and *000*, respectively.

To do this, I added *A1*, to detect when the outputs are all high, and *A2* to detect when they are all low. The outputs of these two detectors are then sent to  *Q4* to *set* and *reset* the direction flow. So, *Q4* can be thought of as a direction controller.

Notice that when *Q4* is *reset* (i.e. has a *0* output) the XOR gates *X1* and *X2* are simply voltage followers of *Q1* and *Q2*. So, *X1* and *X2* essentially become transparent.

When *Q4* is *set* (has a *1* output), *X1* and *X2* invert the outputs of *Q1* and *Q2*, and therefore mimic the \$\bar Q\$ signals. And it is the \$\bar Q\$ signals which are used to create the "down" counter, in the image above.

<sup>1</sup>I'm using the "I" here because there are likely many different ways to accomplish this. Here, I'm just discussing what I did.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry could not fit this in a comment)
I can't tell you why you code is not working but the minimum logic would require only 4 FF's. Three for counting (up or down), one for the direction. 
The direction FF needs to be toggled:

- on 001 if counting down
- on 100 if counting up.

(You need two "comparators" each of 4 bits using the counter state and the direction signal)

The reason why your code is very sub-optimal is that if you have to make a counter which counts up and down to e.g. 255 your shift register becomes a bit big. 
Pseudo code:

```
if (reset)
   count <= 000
   down <= 0
elsif (clock edge)
   if (down) 
      count <= count-1;
   else
      count <= count + 1;
   endif
   if (down and count==001)
      down <= 0;
   else
      if (!down and count==110)
         down <= 1
      endif
   endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given no details of your physical implementation, and no data as to what your physical circuit is actually doing, it is impossible to accurately diagnose your problem.

However, I suggest (based on your diagram) that you are not properly initializing your circuit, especially your 7 FF chain. When you apply power to a real logic circuit there is no guarantee that all of the storage elements (flip-flops) will automatically start at a 0 state. This will have two possible effects:

1) The output of the 7 FF chain probably will not exhibit 7 zeros followed by 7 ones, etc, and your counters will change direction more often than you expect.

2) Even if it does, unless the 3 counter flip-flops also conveniently start at zero the up/down transition will not occur at 000 and 111.

Finally, you do not show your clock source. If it is a push-button switch, like so

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWKGpL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then you will experience contact bounce, and a simple push of the button will generate more than one transition.